# Priority WebSDK getRows(1) returns no data

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, priority-web-sdk

I am using the default code from https://www.npmjs.com/package/priority-web-sdk

```
var configuration = {
    username: '<username>',
    password: '<password>',
    url: '<app server url>',
    tabulaini: 'tabula.ini',
    language: 3,
    company: 'demo'
};

priority.login(configuration)
  .then(()=> priority.formStart('CUSTOMERS', null, null, 'demo', 1))
  .then(form=> form.getRows(1))
  .then(rows=> console.log(rows))
  .catch(err=> console.log(err));
```

if i run the code with my config i get no result however if i remove form.getRows(1) and pass the result of formStart i then get a response and the form info is logged to the console i just can't seam to get any more data?

I am using node but if i include the script on the client side and run it that way then it works fine but this is insecure so not a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you give is an example of what the output looks like when you reach `.then(form=> form.getRows(1))`? - without any follow up code

Comment: I'm assuming there is actually no row 1 for form.getRows(1) to work with, maybe console log form and see what it is. Also it seems from your question that if you pass the result of formStart the result is more to your liking but still not perfect. Perhaps describe what you want to come out and what is coming out instead if you pass formStart and if you don't.

Comment: Sorry for the delay i have been away for a few days, when i run the code and us the getRows(1) i get an Refrence Error: Window is not defined i also run it without the getRows and it returns the correct data. 

form,getRows(1) will get the first 100 rows, yes we do have data as stated if i run the script in the browser rather than server i get back the rows of customers

https://imgur.com/a/uv33RDn

Comment: It would appear that i was missing this although there was no reference to it in the SDK
 ```if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  global.window = {}
   }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the soloution was to check if the window is undefined in my code 
if it is then we should set it.

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    global.window = {}
}
```